# функция создания словаря из строки

Tags: c++, c

```
char* CreateDictionaryText(char* text) {
    сhar tmp;
    char tmp_[2];
    tmp_[1] = '\0';
    char* dictionary = {""};
    for (int i = 0; i < strlen(text); i++) {
        tmp = *(text + i);
        if (strstr(dictionary, &tmp) == 0) {
            tmp_[0] = tmp;
            strcat(dictionary, tmp_);
        }
    }
    return dictionary;
}
```

это функция создания строки-словаря из введенной строки, только она не работает(. Это очень странно, и решения я не нахожу, поэтому обращаюсь к Вам

Comment: Опишите хотя бы, чего Вы хотите от этой функции (что она должна делать). И тег С++ здесь лишний.

Comment: допустим функция принимает в параметры строку "abracadabra". Функция должна возвращать строку "abrcd".

Comment: А почему "abrcd"? Почему не "dabra" или "cabra"?

Comment: ну потому что в dictionary добавляется символ только если его не было. dabra не будет ведь там 2 а

Comment: Перенесите эту информацию непосредственно в вопрос. Так будет легче дать Вам ответ.

Comment: `strlen` как условие цикла по этой же строке приводит к увеличению сложности алгоритма в `n` раз. Не делайте так.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Как минимум что вы хотите от кода, в котором для `dictionary` выделен целый байт, а запихивать вы туда вознамерились явно больше...

Кстати, зачем делать `strstr`, если `strchr` тут явно подойдет лучше? Да и раз уж C++, то сделайте `dictionary` строкой `string` - код существенно упростится, а главное - станет безопасным.

Кстати, если это действительно **C++**, а не C - то, опуская проверки на нулевой указатель etc etc - можно написать просто и незатейливо:

```
char* CreateDictionary(char * text)
{
    sort(text,text+strlen(text));
    *unique(text,text+strlen(text)) = 0;
    return text;
}
```

если, конечно, `text` действительно `char*`, а не `const char*`...

Comment: то есть нужно выделять динамическую память?

Comment: или статическую :)

Comment: @JediCoder Или статическую, как вам уже сказали, но в статической вам придется заранее выделять большой кусок памяти (скажем сразу под 1000 символов, а не под 1 как у вас), а использовать уже как получится (т.е. останутся свободными многие байты скорее всего), но лучше вообще сделать через `std::string` (который под капотом орудует динамической памятью).

Comment: @StateItPrimitive Никак не больше 256 :) - просто потому, что различных символов большее количество не получится...

Comment: @Harry Честно говоря, я не вникал в то, что является словарем здесь, просто заметил факт того, что человек недопонял совет :)

Comment: @Harry про strchr особенно помогло, спасибо

Comment: ох уж эти С++ методы, использовать N log N, там где N хватает :) уже бы set<char> предгать сразу, чего мелочится)

Comment: @pavel Зато какая выразительность! :)

Answer (score 1):

Имея немного времени и вдохновения - вот решение на чистом С, для требовательных - `O(N)`, с памятью `O(1)` :)

```
char * CreateDictionary(const char * text)
{
    char dict[256] = {0};
    int s = 1, d = 0;
    for(;*text;++text) dict[*text] = 1;
    for(;s <= 255; ++s)
        if (dict[s]) dict[d++] = (char)s;
    dict[d] = 0;
    return _strdup(dict);
}
```

Предусловия - `text` не нулевой, `char` - 8-битовый `unsigned`.

Answer (score 0):

```
char* CreateDictionaryText(const char* text) {
char tmp;
int flag = 0;
char tmp_[2];
tmp_[1] = '\0';
char dictionary[256];
for (int i = 0; i < strlen(text); i++) {
    tmp = *(text + i);      
    if (strchr(dictionary, tmp) == 0) {
        tmp_[0] = tmp;
        if (!flag) { 
            strcpy(dictionary, tmp_);
            flag = 1;
        }
        else strcat(dictionary, tmp_);
    }
}
return dictionary;
}

void main() {   
char* text = { "abracadabra" };
char* dictionary = CreateDictionaryText(text);
getchar();
}
```

работающий код, спасибо за участие

Comment: Не работающий! У вас `dictionary` - локальный массив в стеке! Нельзя возвращать указатель на него из функции! И, кстати, вы его не инициализировали - он содержит мусор! Возвращать уж лучше `strdup(dictionary)`...  Или объявить `static char dictionary[256]`, но тогда новый вызов функции будет портить старую строку. И еще - я бы занулил весь `dictionary` и держал индекс первого пустого места в нем. И вместо создания строки и `strcat` просто присваивал бы символ как `dictionary[index++] = tmp`...

Comment: Как вариант можно предложить такой прототип функции `int CreateDictionaryText (const char *text, char dict[], int dict_size);` Функция будет возвращать реальный размер словаря, память под который размером `dict_size` (с учетом места для завершающего нуля) предоставляет вызывающая программа. А для эффективной работы внутри можно использовать битовый массив на 255 бит (займет 32 байта локальной памяти), который вначале обнуляется. По мере просмотра `text` будем устанавливать биты, с индексом равным коду `text[i]` в этом массиве в 1. Если символ встретился первый раз он помещается в конец `dict`.